# How can I find and hide the parents of elements with a given text content using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

In the example below, I'm trying to figure out how to hide the fieldset if the text within the  tags = Groups

```
<fieldset class=" collapsible">
<legend class="collapse-processed"><a href="#">Groups</a></legend>
```

I tried this, but, it winds up hiding all the fieldsets, not just this one...

```
$(this).find('legend').each( function() {
    if($(this).text('Groups')) {
        $(this).parent().hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
if ($(this).text('Groups'))
```

This just changes the text of every *legend* to be "Groups". And returns a jQuery object (which will evaluate to *true*). You probably want something like,

```
if ( $(this).text() == 'Groups' )
  $(this).parent().hide();
```

If you can guarantee that the legends you wish to hide are the only ones *containing* the word "Groups", then you could simplify this further:

```
$("fieldset:has(legend:contains('Groups'))").hide();
```

...which will select only those *fieldset*s containing a *legend* element that in turn contains the character sequence "Groups".

Comment: Ahh... Thank you.  Still learning syntax, so I really appreciate it.